# Show that $f(n) = \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(1+i)\right)^n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, divergent-series

I am having this sequence:
$$f (n)= \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(1+i)\right)^n$$
I think it is divergent, because I found a subsequence that is divergent:

The subsequence $4n$ shows that the sequence alternates between $1$ and  $-1$.

---

Questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. How can I write my reflections down in a formally correct way?

Comment: Your reasoning looks good to me. Perhaps you can write this up in a 'formally correct way' if you recognize your sequence as $a^n$ where $a$ is a primitive 8th root of unity.

Comment: It is correct. Formally $4n$ itself is not the subsequence. It is $f(4n)$ that is a subsequence, and it alternates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt2}2(1+i)=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}i=e^{\frac\pi4i}\implies$$

$$f(n)=e^{\frac{n\pi}4i}=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;n=0\pmod 8\\\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)&,\;\;n=1\pmod8\\i&,\;\;n=2\pmod8\\\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1+i)&,\;\;n=3\pmod 8\\-1&,\;\;n=4\pmod 8\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)&,\;\;n=5\pmod 8\\-i&,\;\;n=6\pmod 8\\\frac1{\sqrt2}(1-i)&,\;\;n=7\pmod 8\end{cases}$$

Thus, as $\;n\to\infty\;,\;\;f(n)\;\;$  approaches nothing: it keeps on attaining all the eight values above.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct. Since
$$|f(4n+4)-f(4n)|=2\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$$
the sequence is not a Cauchy sequence, and hence it diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$f(n) = \left( \frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}(1+i)\right)^n =\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot i\right)^n = \left(e^{i\pi/4}\right)^n = e^{i\pi n/4}$$

Hence $$f(4n) = e^{i\pi n} = (-1)^n$$
which diverges when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The number $\sqrt{2}(1+i)/2$ has complex modulus 1 and angle $\pi/4$. Thus, the sequence $f(n)$ dances around the origin along the vertices of a regular octagon.

Comment: "dances around" is not formal :)